# How to divide one column with another in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and there are four columns and I have numbers in two of those columns. I want to divide one column with another, so let's say in one column there is number 20 and in another column there is 4 and I want to divide those two, so I should get the number 5.

How would I do that? Here is my schema:

[image: A screenshot of my schema]

I want to divide `ocena` with `st_ocen`.

Update: if I use this `string Query = "SELECT ocena / st_ocen FROM filmi.film WHERE film = Deadspeed 2013";` (since I am making this in C#) I get this error:

> Could not find specified column in results: ocena

Comment: You say your table has the column `ocena`, but when you run a query that requires that column, it says it is not there. This is a problem for you to sort out, not someone else here. You could start by verifying what table you have shown us (is it really "film"?) and what database it is in (is it really in "filmi")?

Comment: (Aside: please try to avoid chatroom speak, such as "cuz", and to format posts carefully. They don't have to be poetry or perfect English, but a little effort may keep some downvotes at bay, and saves on editing work. Thanks.)

Comment: i m 100% sure it is in database filmi and it is table film checked it twice i m getting that error all the time could not find specified column in results: ocena

Comment: OK, so do this on the MySQL command line: `USE filmi;` then a newline, then `DESCRIBE film`. This will switch to the database in question, then describe the table in question. One or both of them should raise an error. Please edit into your question what you get from both.

Comment: Also, your query has a syntax error in it - your `WHERE` clause should have quotes around the string i.e. `WHERE film = 'Deadspeed 2013'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   SELECT ocena / st_ocen 
   FROM  filmi 
   WHERE film = 'Deadspeed 2013'
   AND st_ocen != 0
```

Comment: `Could not find specified column in results: ocena` thats what i get

Comment: Something is wrong in what you are doing. The field ocena is the one that you mention so, it must exist!

Comment: it may be wrong your column name ocena in database. check if you have spaces before or after this name in database.

Comment: no spaces.. and i have been getting data from that table before and it worked now i just want to devide those 2 column but i m geting this error atm..